# nginx redirect to www.domain

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect, rewrite

I want to redirect the site ALWAYS to www.site.com. However, I am not sure as to how to get the WWW to always show up in front should say someone type in the domain without the www.

EDIT:

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  site.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.site.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.site.com;
    #rewrite ^(.*) https://www.site.com$1 permanent;
    root /home/site/public_html;

        listen       443 ssl;
```

If I type in site.com it goes to `https://www.site.com` = SUCCESS

If I type in site.com/index.php it goes to `http://www.site.com` = NO SSL

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the hard way. Here's the easy way.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    #The rest of your configuration goes here#
}
```

Answer (score 29):

It's better to use `return` instead of `rewrite`, because it's faster.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     example.com;
    return          301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    [...]
}
```

This way, we also send the client a proper status code, so that he asks the right domain in the next request.

Comment: Gave you an upvote, but thought I'd note that `rewrite permanent` sends a 301, too.

Comment: Shouldn't `server` have the closing tag `}` ?