# redirect from non-www to www with https on elastic beanstalk using nginx for a ruby on rail application

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk

I have a ruby on rails application setup on AWS elastic beanstalk using nginx and puma, my requirement is to redirect all my requests from `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` or `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. Also I don't want request from my subdomains to be redirected to www, like I don't want `http://subdomain.example.com` to be redirected to `https://www.expample.com` or `https://www.subdomain.example.com`.

Using the link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297375/how-to-get-elastic-beanstalk-nginx-backed-proxy-server-to-auto-redirect-from-htt

I was able to redirect all my requests from http to https but this does not redirect non www to www requests.

Comment: This should be probably posted on serverfault. Apart from that, you need to create a virtual server for each domain you want to redirect and redirect it permanently to where you want it to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx redirect to www.domain](http://serverfault.com/questions/502026/nginx-redirect-to-www-domain)

Comment: @TeroKilkanen the link you provided does not solve my problem entirely, I need a solution for a Elastic beanstalk server using nginx and not just nginx (you could refer to the link provided in question for the type of solution I  need)

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my `routes.rb` file:

```
# Redirect example.com => www.example.com
constraints(host: /^example\.com/i) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect { |params, _req| "https://www.example.com/#{params[:path]}" }, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

This will for both non-secure and secure connections to https, but if you really need to keep `http` requests as non-secure, then you could have a more specific constraint.