# Special redirect NGINX Wordpress removing last segment

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

I need some guidance on how to redirect this the proper way...

I have a site on `nginx` and a bunch of malformed `URL's` (crawled by `Search Console`) that I need to redirect with `301`.

My `CMS` is `Wordpress` and I need to redirect these `URL's` to `/post_url/` removing all sufixes after 1 segment (`/post_url/`).

**Malformed `URL's` examples:**

- `https://www.example.com/post_url/tag/tag-one`
- `https://www.example.com/post_url/tag/tag-two`
- `https://www.example.com/post_url/tag/tag-three`
- etc.

I also need to preserve all `tag's` `URL` working like so => (`https://www.example.com/tag/whatever`), and I have no clue on how to do it...

Comment: Don't attempt to do this in nginx - configure the redirects in Wordpress.

Comment: @symcbean I'm missing the regex part... Can you elaborate?

Comment: The specific syntax (and whether it uses regexes) will depend on which plugin you use for this.

Comment: but I don't want to use plugins...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this relevant question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-can-i-create-custom-url-routes . There are other options such as using htaccess or a plugin to perform the redirects. Here is another relevant question for nginx, [How to redirect requests to a different domain/url with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/307925/how-to-redirect-requests-to-a-different-domain-url-with-nginx) . If you have a specific issue with your nginx config, it'd be helpful to post that.

Comment: I'm missing the regex part... Can you elaborate?